# Install electron on node for windows hangs

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron, npm-install

I am following the quick installtion guide on electron :http://electron.atom.io/

Script:

## Clone the Quick Start repository

`git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start`

## Go into the repository

`cd electron-quick-start`

## Install the dependencies and run

`npm install && npm start`

The installation is stuck at :

`Node Install.js` - this command is executed with `npm install && npm start`.

Is there a way i could find out what `node install.js` is doing in the backend to workout why it's stuck?

Comment: Did it complete? I myself was also stuck on this one. I am using Mac OSX and my first install was like in almost 24 hours nothing happens with no feedback. I tried it again today but still no success for me. So, did you complete it? Could you give us more info in case it works for you now? Thanks.

Comment: any success with this one - using VSC windows 10 hangs in the built in terminal with `node install.js` as the last line

Comment: It's a sign from the universe that you should never build an electron app

Comment: I'm wondering if they have certain regions blocked?  Or maybe if they block VPNs?  Trying to fish the info out.  Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue because of slow download rate. 
As suggested by other answers try running `npm install --verbose` to see what is hanging. In my case, it was downloading the electron package at **20kb/s** speed!.
[image]
With a little bit of investigation, I could find that electron is delegating the download task to `electron-download` package(https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-download).

In the `electron-download` documentation,  there are few ways to set the location/mirror where electron package could be downloaded.

Instead of setting up a local mirror as explained in the documentation, I manually downloaded the package from China mirror(https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/1.6.12/). I could get the package under 5 min. Then copied both package and SHASUMS256.txt to `%USERPROFILE%\.electron` folder.

Rerun the `npm install --verbose` and it was no longer hanging.

Answer (score 11):

with `--verbose` it makes it much more obvious if you're somehow interrupting the electron module download during node_modules install 
this will help to correct this by observing the download and installation process with:

```
npm install electron -g --verbose
```

With this command you will install global Electron. You can not cancel until the download process is complete. Delete the folder node_modules and reinstall.

Answer (score 6):

Checking out the electron/install.js file, it does download some files and installs them actually. So based on your bandwidth it may take some time.

```
// downloads if not cached
download({
  version: version,
  platform: process.env.npm_config_platform,
  arch: process.env.npm_config_arch,
  strictSSL: process.env.npm_config_strict_ssl === 'true',
  quiet: ['info', 'verbose', 'silly', 'http'].indexOf(process.env.npm_config_loglevel) === -1
}, extractFile)

// unzips and makes path.txt point at the correct executable
function extractFile (err, zipPath) {
  if (err) return onerror(err)
  fs.writeFile(path.join(__dirname, 'path.txt'), paths[platform], function (err) {
    if (err) return onerror(err)
    extract(zipPath, {dir: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')}, function (err) {
      if (err) return onerror(err)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Give it time, it will complete. You would not see a progress but it is executing in the backend.

Answer (score 5):

**Yarn is the key**

I tried `npm` for two hours

- no bandwidth usage in latest `electron@7.1.10`
- 4 Kbps on `electron@6.0.0`

**so RIGHT Steps:**

1. *powershell as admin is recommended*
2. Delete node modules/electron folder in %appdata% if installing *golbally* or from application folder if *locally*
3. Install [yarn](https://legacy.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable)
4. Run this command: `yarn global add electron --verbose`
5. Monitor your bandwidth from task manager *( mine was about 500 Kbps and finished in 270s )*
6. if this is the first time for you with yarn run `yarn global bin`
   ,it'll give you a path copy & paste it to `PATH` in environment variables

[image: elctron install success]

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue on a Windows 10 machine

- Delete the %appdata%/npm/node_modules folder
- Run command prompt in administrator mode.

The installation succeeded when I did these steps. Hope it helps someone else too

Answer (score 3):

try `npm install -g --verbose electron` it works like charm.

**It installs the module + show you the progress**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wait until it finishes it's background works while it seems hang but not. I also faced this problem and realized its background work was running by checking download speed of my modem manager. See the following image that DL speed is near 2mbps.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just hold on for a while and grab a coffee it will complete.If you are not sure about the download really happening ...keep checking the size of node modules(should be increasing) and also according to the previous answers checking stats of your data connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you get Electron 404 error on **taobao** source.

Try change:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.0.0"
  }
```

to for example

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^6.0.1"
  }
```

Comment: it's just ridiculous that everybody complained this hanging issue, happened to me as well, and my connection is not bad, certainly downloading stuff regularly from github but electron 8.0.1 definitely hanged and my network shows 1kb download speed for my whole computer. Just used 6.0.1 and downloaded super fast. I don't think the issue is related with github or internet connection. The post install script may be definitely picking wrong mirror or something similar

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue for a long time. I tried installing on different network and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mirror with higher download speed.

Try this one:

```
ELECTRON_MIRROR="https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/" ELECTRON_CUSTOM_DIR="{{ version }}" npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded using `npm` with `--verbose`, using an Ethernet cable and after about 40 minutes (my speed was about 200kb) it downloaded successfully.

Comment: Crediting correctly if your solution is baed on an existing answer or comment is very much appreciated. I deleted that however because I got the impression that you only state that it did NOT work. Please review my change and feel free to [edit] according to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

1. I used yarn instead of npm.
2. Opened powershell as "ADMIN".
3. yarn add electron --dev --verbose
4. wait
   Finally, it is installed. The crucial point is to open powershell or cmd or terminal in admin mode.